# Unable to create numeric directories via sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I have the following sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

UPLOAD_DIR="/var/www/upload"
mkdir -p "${UPLOAD_DIR}"{0..99} && chown -R www-data "${UPLOAD_DIR}"/*
```

But instead of creating of directories from 0 to 99 the script above generates the single folder named `{0..99}`. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: thank for the answers. I have one more question in this post. How to create directories with leadring padding to two symbols? For example `01`, `02`...`10`, `11` ?

Comment: `/bin/sh` doesn't support that brace syntax.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/682421/unable-to-create-numeric-directories-via-sh-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash` to use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

upload_dir='/var/www/upload'
mkdir -p "${upload_dir}"/{0..99} && chown -R www-data "${upload_dir}"/{0..99}
```

This feature is also available in ksh and zsh (possibly more) but as you tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I assume that's what you want to use.

As an aside, there was a subtle bug in your code - there was a `/` in the argument passed to `chown` but not `mkdir`. I have also changed your variable name to be lowercase, as all-uppercase variable names should be reserved for shell internal and [system-wide environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html).

---

A nice feature of brace expansions is that you can generate a sequence `00`, `01`, `02`, `..`, `99` by using `{00..99}`. Note that this requires a new-ish version of bash (version 4+, I'm told).

Thanks to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for the helpful input.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I execute my script via `sh ./script.sh`. If I change  `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` how could I run my script then?

Comment: @Erik you should execute your script using `bash script.sh`, or make it executable (e.g. `chmod +x script.sh`) and then run it directly `./script.sh`.

Comment: `sh` and `bash` should be treated as two separate programs. If you want to use bash features, don't use `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

OR, ...   make it a function, so if you're running  bash, then you don't have to worry about the need to sh-bang:  UNTESTED.

```
 md_chown () { mkdir -p "$1"/{00..99} && chown -R www-data "$1"/{00..99}; }
```

and invoked:

```
 md_chown /var/www/upload
```